# How to make smart-gwt application resolution independent?

Tags: smartgwt

I am developing smart gwt application, As per smart FAQ we have to give smart gwt component height, width in pixels. 
Giving size in pixels will not behave uniform in all resolutions.

Can anybody tell how to make it resolution independent? so it behave uniform in all resolutions?

Thanks,
Punam Purohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SmartGWt we can specify height or width in terms of percentage or pixels. if u see in layout or canvas or any item's function will have setWidth(String width) & setHeight(String height), this string parameter will accept either pixels or percentage 
values.

for ex: Vlayout.setWidth("50%") this will set 50% of screen size to that corresponding layout obj.

Refer javadoc of any SetWidth or setHeight : http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setWidth%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SmartGWT in a while, but I remember that most of the widgets were overloading a setWidth value which accepted %.

Anyway, the proper way should be using layouts to compose the position of your widgets.